# Nhibernate Extension points

Tags: nhibernate

I'm looking for more information on the extension points within NHibernate.

For instance I know about IUserType and ICacheProvider. However I can't seem to find a good reference of all the different extension points that NHibernate provides?

Is anyone's Google-fu stronger than mine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no complete references on that... but it's not hard to look at the assembly and find the interfaces and base classes:

- IInterceptor
- IBatcherFactory
- ICollectionTypeFactory
- IProxyFactoryFactory
- ICacheProvider
- IConnectionProvider
- ICurrentSessionContext
- Dialect
- IDriver
- IIdentifierGenerator
- ITuplizer
- And many more...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at *EventListener (newer mechanism) and IInterceptor (older mechanism, but useful in certain scenarios that EventListeners don't cover). They will get you a long way WRT extending/integrating with NHibernate.

http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#events